# DES Encryption in Python

Tags: python-3.x, des

The pycryptodome is working fine, but I'm getting an error message.

Here's my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

key = 'hello123'

def pad(text):
        while len(text) % 8 != 0:
            text += ''
        return text

des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)

text1 = 'Python is the Best Language!'

padded_text = pad(text1)

encrypted_text = des.encrypt(padded_text)

print(encrypted_text)

print(des.decrypt(encrypted_text))
```

This is my error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Raj_7\Desktop\des.py", line 10, in 
>       des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py", line 145, in new
>       return _create_cipher(sys.modules[**name**], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
>       return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher_mode_ecb.py", line 215, in _create_ecb_cipher
>       cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py", line 76, in _create_base_cipher
>       result = start_operation(c_uint8_ptr(key),
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util_raw_api.py", line 234, in c_uint8_ptr
>
> raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
>   TypeError: Object type  cannot be passed to C code

Comment: Please type in your sample code and error code here. Don't post it with image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the code , the error is not formatting correctly so its in the pic

Comment: error message must by typed in, it cannot be entered as a pic, as per SO guidelines.  It's too difficult to read text in images, especially on mobile devices.  Also, the ability to copy-paste relevant parts of the error message into search engines, or even StackOverflow is often a good way to find the answers to problems.  Volunteers will want this ability.  Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). then `edit` accordingly.  Preceed the error message with a `>` at the beginning of the line to format it as quote or error message.

Comment: even if you cannot get the formatting for the error message correct, you need to type it in.  Someone else can help you with the formatting, then you can look to see how they did it.  Basically preceed it with a `>`, and adding two spaces at the end of a line will produce a line break, but keep the next line formatted.

Comment: i added the spaces current one is fine ?

Answer (score 3):

It works here if I use [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instead of strings

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

def pad(text):
    n = len(text) % 8
    return text + (b' ' * n)


key = b'hello123'
text1 = b'Python is the Best Language!'

des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)

padded_text = pad(text1)
encrypted_text = des.encrypt(padded_text)

print(encrypted_text)
print(des.decrypt(encrypted_text))
```

Comment: From https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html  : Plaintexts and ciphertexts (input/output) can only be bytes, bytearray or memoryview. In Python 3, you cannot pass strings. In Python 2, you cannot pass Unicode strings.

Comment: you should use '\x00' for padding, not ' '.

Comment: It works for me if I use a while loop but this method does not work for me.